# SQL-Alchemy one-to-one relationship enforcement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I set up a one-to-one relationship between two tables `user` and `transaction` using SQL-Alchemy relationships and following their [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html).

Creating two transactions `t1`, `t2` connected to the same user `u` (which shouldn't be possible under a 1:1 relationship) and committing both results in the foreign key of `t1` being set to `NULL` in the database with no error being thrown.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///storage.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('transaction', uselist=False))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(bind=engine)
u = User()
t1 = Transaction()
t1.user = u
session.add(t1)
session.commit()

t2 = Transaction()
t2.user = u
session.add(t2)
session.commit()
```

`t1.user` evaluates to `NULL` after the execution

This might quickly lead to an undesirable database state, is this behaviour desired or is there a way to strictly enforce the foreign key relationship?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726070/does-sqlalchemy-really-have-one-to-one-relationships

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to set the the foreign key to UNIQUE and NOT NULL, that is:

```
   user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

That ensures an exception is raised once the two elements with the same foreign key are inserted into the database. As the ORM doesn't touch the database while the objects are being created, it has no way of ensuring the consistency of the database up until the point of insertion.